# jquery - Change IMG src on rollover

Tags: jquery, image, attr, closest

I've the following code: ([a fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/cordial/U7SNz/))

```
<img class="changeable" src="http://placehold.it/100x120&text=anniversary">
    <ul class="rollover_list">
        <li><a href="#" rel="http://placehold.it/100x120&text=anniversary"><span class="orange">> </span>Anniversary</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="http://placehold.it/100x120&text=birthday"><span class="orange">> </span>Birthday</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="http://placehold.it/100x120&text=christmas"><span class="orange">> </span>Christmas</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" rel="http://placehold.it/100x120&text=wedding"><span class="orange">> </span>Wedding</a></li>
    </ul>
```

and I'm attempting to change the src attribute of the image based on the rel value of the anchor.

I'm trying this jquery -

```
$("ul.rollover_list li a").hover(function() {
            var $link = $(this).attr('rel');
            var $target = $(this).closest('img.changeable');
            $($target).attr('src', $link);
        });
```

as I need to use it multiple times on a page.

Am I right in thinking that .closest() will locate the nearest matching element by traversing up the DOM?

Don't know what I'm missing but it ain't happy.

Comment: `$target` is already a jQuery object, you don't need to jQuerize it again with `$($target)`. Apart from that, what's exactly your problem? What makes you unhappy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 2 problems in your jQuery:

1. jQuery's `closest()` method only works in trees, in other words: it will only work if the wanted result is a parent of the current element.
2. `$($target)`. `$target` is already an element, you can't select an element using an element as a selector, for that you'd need a method like `find` however, this isn't what you were trying to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/U7SNz/2/

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do, but I'm going to have lots of these on a page so I'd like a version that will just find the img.changeable that's nearest the ul. Would you have any suggestions as to how I might do that? Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: if it's always ordered like that, it's easy: `$(this).closest('ul').prev()` : http://jsfiddle.net/U7SNz/3/

Answer (score 5):

That line that appears as...

```
$($target).attr('src', $link);
```

should probably be...

```
$target.attr('src', $link);
```

Comment: This doesn't fully solve the problem, there's still an issue with the `jquery.closest` method she's using.